# JQuery Validation SubmitHandler for multiple forms on same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have been using successfully the jQuery Validation script. But now I have the need to put two forms on one webpage.

I found the code to standardize the Validate rules and such, but I'm stumped on how to use what I've been using for inside the "submitHandler" part. I've been using it to produce a spinner gif (hide/show).

But now with having two forms on the same page, either one will activate the other spinner or they both activate or none activates when either submit button is clicked.

Any ideas on how to separate this out?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').each(function() {
    $(this).validate({
        // edited out non-relevant code for this question //

        submitHandler: function(form) {

            $('#submitSpin').show();
            $('#submitButt').hide();
            form.submit();

        }, // END submitHandler

    }); // END this validate
  }); // END form each function
}); // END document ready function
```

So clearly I can't use the same ID for both forms' buttons; but if I make them different, I'm not sure how to write "IF this form is submitted, then show/hide these ID's, but if THIS OTHER form is submitted, then show/hide THESE other ID's" (so to speak).

Comment: Just use the `form` argument of the `submitHandler` to only target the specific form object... the same way that `form.submit()` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like `form.submit()`, simply use the `form` argument that is passed into the `submitHandler`.  It represents the form object.  Then use jQuery to find and target its spinner.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).find('.submitSpin').show();
    $(form).find('.submitButt').hide();
    form.submit();
}, // END submitHandler
```

Be sure to never repeat any `id` on the page, so `submitSpin` and `submitButt` can only be class names.

**Proof-of-concept DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/0g0oaonL/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/0g0oaonL/2/)**

Comment: Oops, just found out this works fine in Chrome but does not work in Safari. the form does submit, but the show/hide just doesn't happen. hmmm.

Comment: @SyberKnight, my jsFiddle demo was written using Safari and works fine.  jQuery `.show()` and `.hide()` are very straightforward methods, and since jQuery is normalized to work across browsers including Safari, that does not make any sense.

Comment: you are right! something must be wrong with what i'm doing or there's a conflict with something else. i've just spent the past day pouring over it, picking it apart, trying things without other stuff & i can't find the problem. it works on fiddle & codepen by itself, but in my page, it's not. i read something elsewhere about Safari not doing something with JS correctly, but... over my head. anyways, i have this on Sign-Up, Sign-In, Forgot Pwd, Giving, & Fundraising pages. here's one for ref... http://sanctuaryinternational.com/giving/fundraiser.html

Comment: i did at first, which lead me to dissect the whole page, & i found the error. but apparently it didn't have anything to do with this issue (lol). it's so strange; it works on my iPhone in Safari, just not on my Mac. i've turned off all extensions & run as vanilla as possible, but no diff. every now & then the hide/show does seem to fire off, but gets stuck. such a little thing yet so frustrating.

Comment: @ShaziaNusrat, I have no idea what you're talking about.   Your comments have nothing to do with anything on this page.